Spring Integration handleReactive() - Missing TraceId
.handleReactive() terminal operator does NOT log with traceId / spanId. ReactiveContext seems to be lost.
Please take a look at the below sample depicting the problem. Thanks
https://github.com/syedyusufh/simple-handle-reactive.git

Looks like we are missing the Reactor context propagation for that part of the framework. Please, raise a GitHub issue and we will look ASAP. Thanks

Thanks Artem, have raised https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/9110
